# Why is NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification being called several times in quick succession?

Tags: ios, icloud, nsmetadataquery

In order to monitor file changes in my iCloud container, I've registered for

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(processiCloudUpdates:)
                                             name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Ideally, whenever I receive the message that updates have been made, I'd like to open each of my UIDocs and check if settings have been changed. This would be fine, if `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification` was only called once. However, it is being fired several times (I did not forget to `removeObserver` etc. and have several instances running), and it would thus make it highly impractical to load all files every time the update notification is being fired (if I had 5 files and this is being called 4 times, I'd open 20 UIDocs in quick succession). For instance, this happens if I update one file (and only have one file in my ubiquitous container):

```
2012-07-05 10:51:39.565 Meernotes[7842:707] ... NSMetadataQuery update
2012-07-05 10:51:42.468 Meernotes[7842:707] ... NSMetadataQuery update
2012-07-05 10:51:45.216 Meernotes[7842:707] ... NSMetadataQuery update
2012-07-05 10:51:47.036 Meernotes[7842:707] ... NSMetadataQuery update
```

Is there any other way to determine when a file has changed? NSFileVersion did not help much either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification` issues each time when some of attributes of any `NSMetadataItem` in `NSMetadataQuery` results update. It includes the the partial upload or download progress. So it is wrong to try to open `UIDocument` instance during this notification handling.

Instead you could determine the moment when the document did download by observing the attribute values of `NSMetadataItem` and then queue it to be opened.

Do not forget to handle `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification` too. It is posted when the receiver has finished with the initial result - gathering phase of the query

Comment: I think the question "How to monitor changes in the iCloud?"still remains.